# Let $x = (a^2+a+1)^{1/2}-(a^2-a+1)^{1/2}$ and $a$ belongs to real number find all possible value of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $A = (-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$, $B = (1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$, and $P = (a, 0)$. Then $P$ is a point on the $X$-axis and we are looking for all possible values of $d = PA - PB$.

By the Triangle Inequality, $PA - PB < AB = 1$. And it is clear
that all the values $-1 < d < 1$ are indeed obtainable. In fact, for such
a $d$, a half hyperbola of all points $Q$ such that $QA - QB = d$ is well
defined. (Points $A$ and $B$ are foci of the hyperbola.) Since line $AB$ is parallel to the $X$-axis, this half hyperbola intersects the
$X$- axis, i.e., $P$ is well defined.

I know that at point $A$ and $B$ the two above $\sqrt{\cdot}$ function will obtain minimum value respectively

I am not able to understand why are we looking for all the possible value of $d$, what is the relationship of $d$ with the possible value of $x$?

This is question number 14 from 101 problems in algebra (USAIMO)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Well, $d=x$ as i suppose you are only looking for the positive roots of the relevant expressions, so not sure why you have different variables for the same thing. As you have noted, all values in $(-1,1)$ are possible, and nothing else - prove that and you should be done. In case $(...)^{½} $ can be negative as well, then it is a different story - why don't you mention the exact wording of the question? Is it as stated in your title, or the first para of your post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the range of possible values of $\sqrt{a^2+a+1}-\sqrt{a^2-a+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168265/find-the-range-of-possible-values-of-sqrta2a1-sqrta2-a1)

Answer (score 0):

Since
$a^{1/2}-b^{1/2}
=(a^{1/2}-b^{1/2})\dfrac{a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}}{a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}}
=\dfrac{a-b}{a^{1/2}+b^{1/2}}
$,
$d(a)
=(a^2+a+1)^{1/2}-(a^2-a+1)^{1/2}
=\dfrac{2a}{(a^2+a+1)^{1/2}+(a^2-a+1)^{1/2}}
$.

Also,
by the generalized mean inequality,
$\sqrt{uv}
\le (\dfrac{\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}}{2})^2
\le \dfrac{u+v}{2}
$
or
$2\sqrt[4]{uv}
\le\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}
\le \sqrt{2(u+v)}
$
so
$d(a)
\ge \dfrac{2a}{\sqrt{4(a^2+1)}}
= \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
d(a)
&\le \dfrac{2a}{2\sqrt[4]{(a^2+a+1)(a^2-a+1)}}\\
&= \dfrac{a}{\sqrt[4]{(a^2+1)^2-a^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{a}{\sqrt[4]{a^4+a^2+1}}\\
&\le 1\\
\end{array}
$

So the range of values is from
$0$ to $1$.